# CBV, IBV and VBV byte alignment

Tags: directx12

The CBV (constant buffer view) `SizeInBytes` is required to be 256-byte aligned.

Should the associated `ID3D12Resource` have a `Width` (i.e. `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC`) equal to/greater than that same size or may it be smaller, as the additional padding of the CBV won't be accessed/used in the shaders anyway? For example, is it allowed to create a CBV with `SizeInBytes` equal to 256 bytes for a `ID3D12Resource` with `Width` equal to 64 bytes?

Are there constraints for the IBV (index buffer view) and VBV (vertex buffer view) `SizeInBytes` as well?